# ModuleNotFoundError when trying to import python file which itself imports a file in the same directory

Tags: python, import, module

I have a python project with the following file structure:

```
- Project
     - Driver
          - __init__.py
          - driver.py
          - helper_functions.py
     - test.py
```

the first two lines inside driver.py are:

```
import helper_functions as hf
import socket
```

the entire contents of test.py are:

```
from Driver.driver import driver

driver = driver("192.168.1.101",2268)
```

When I run test.py, i get the error

```
    import helper_functions as hf
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'helper_functions'
```

If i change driver.py to have

```
import Driver.helper_functions as hf
import socket
```

this fixes the issue with running test.py, but then any files inside the Driver directory that try to import driver, for example if i have

```
from driver import driver
```

in my **init**.py file, running it produces the error

```
    import Driver.helper_functions as hf
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Driver'
```

how can i fix this so that i can import driver from inside Driver folder and outside

Answer (score 0):

You can just change

```
import helper_functions as hf
```

to

```
from Driver import helper_functions as hf
```

or to

```
from . import helper_functions
```

The first one is an import with absolute path, the second one, is relative.

Comment: that solves the issue when im importing the Driver module from somewhere outside the Driver module itself, but then if i run import driver from anywhere inside the module i get the error 'No module named 'Driver', is this something i cant avoid when creating packages?

Comment: What module were you talking about when you wrote "i run import driver from anywhere inside the module"?

Comment: I don't know, if i get it right, but when you want to import something from the file `Driver/driver.py` to a file, let's say `Driver/abc.py` it is not found? I just reproduced that and for me it works when I have `abc.py` in the Driver directory. I just call `from Driver import driver`

Comment: when I do that i get ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Driver'